# Error: Error: Could not find or load main class neon.Main

Tags: java, javafx

I'm writing an application, but I recieve the error message named in the title. In the src folder is under the package neon the class Main.java. The package neon.friends contains Friends.fxml. And the package neon.views contains MainItemsController.java, MainItems.fxml and MainView.fxml.

Here is the code of the main class:

```
    package neon;

import java.io.IOException;


import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

private Stage primaryStage;
private static  BorderPane mainLayout;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
    this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
    this.primaryStage.setTitle("Neon");
    showMainView();
    showMainItems();
}

private void showMainView() throws IOException{
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("view/MainView.fxml"));
    mainLayout = loader.load();
    Scene scene = new Scene(mainLayout);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

private void showMainItems() throws IOException{
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("view/MainItems.fxml"));
    BorderPane mainItems = loader.load();
    mainLayout.setCenter(mainItems);
}

public static void showFriends() throws IOException{
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("friends/Friends.fxml"));
    BorderPane friends = loader.load();
    mainLayout.setCenter(friends);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

Comment: check your CLASSPATH.

Comment: Is it possible that github is the problem? My other projects are working well (i don't use github with them)

Comment: How your are trying to run main class? On a server or directly as java app?

Comment: How do you build your jar, and what command are you invoking from the command line? It really seems that the `neon.Main` class is not found in your classpath- have you checked if the class is included in your jar?

Comment: I use Eclipse. How can I check if the class is included in my jar?